# Laravel - how to insert json in database

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

here si my model

```
class Gallery extends Model{ protected $table = 'gallery';

protected $fillable = [
    'id','pages_id','title','subtitle'
];

protected $casts =[
    'photo'=>'array'
];
```

}

here is the controller

```
public function add_gallery(Request $request, $id)
{
    $gal = Gallery::create([
        'title' => $request['titlu'],
        'subtitle' => $request['autor'],
        'photo' => json_encode($p),
        'pages_id' => $id
    ]);

}
```

the line
'photo' => json_encode($p) does not work, it says that column photo is empty, $p is not empty

Comment: You need to add `photo` to the `$fillable` attributes. Regarding `json_encode()`: Because of the cast, you can/need to use `'photo' => $p,`.

Comment: but i would have 2 photos, do i have to delete the cast?

Comment: What type of data is `$p`? An array?

Comment: yes $p is an array

Comment: Then `'photo' => $p,` is correct. The cast takes care of encoding the array as JSON.

Comment: this is the error SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'photo' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `gallery` (`title`, `subtitle`, `pages_id`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (cancer, gras, 1, 2020-04-06 21:05:33, 2020-04-06 21:05:33))

Comment: Did you add `photo` to `$fillable`?

Comment: no, do i have to?

Comment: Yes, that's what I wrote in my first comment.

Comment: the thing is that i did not have to use it when i populated the db with ->save() method

Comment: it worked thanks, but i dont understand why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. $photo should be added to $fillable

   ```
   protected $fillable = ['id','pages_id','title','subtitle','photo'];
   ```
2. Since You do using casting, You do not use json_encode/json_decode manually because Laravel is doing it for You.

   ```
   $gal = Gallery::create([
      'title' => $request['titlu'],
      'subtitle' => $request['autor'],
      'photo' => $p,
      'pages_id' => $id
   ]);
   ```
3. $p variable is not present in add_gallery() method.